# Why function showStar() does not work with (Return) and instead of increasing star according to row?

Tags: javascript

```
function showStars(number) {

    for (let i= 0; i <=number; i++) {
      let star = "";
      for (let s = 0; s <= i; s++)
         star += "*";
      return star; 
    }
}
```

console.log(showStars(3)) // just one star

Comment: it works well with console.log inside the code  like this    
                                                          
   function showStars(number) {
            for (let i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
                let star = "";
                for (let s = 0; s <= i; s++)
                    star += "*";

                console.log(star);
            }
        }
        showStars(3)

Comment: What is the intended output? Are you expecting to get 3 stars or 9 stars? For 3 stars, you only need one `for` loop. But you have two, which would give 9.

Comment: Hello aya hosny, and welcome to StackOverflow! Please don't name your question with your specific method and find something more generic. Have a good day!

Comment: @ayahosny, you submitted a confusing edit to my answer. Could you explain?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `return` outside of both `for` loops.
After you `return` a value, none of the code after it (including second iterations of the loop) gets run.

The code should be like this:

```
function showStars(number) {

    for (let i= 0; i <=number; i++) {
      let star = "";
      for (let s = 0; s <= i; s++)
         star += "*";

    }

    return star; 
}
```

EDIT:
Also, your star variable is being reset on every iteration of the loop.

I'm not sure what your intended output is, but I think perhaps you meant to do this?

```
function showStars(number) {

    let star = "";

    for (let i= 0; i < number; i++) {

      star += "*";

    }

    return star; 
}
```